# How to specify only the type of List to use as your container on a method

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface and it looks like the following

```
public interface IModelConverter<TSourceModel, TDestinationModel>
{
    TListType ToDestination<TListType>(IEnumerable<TSourceModel> source)
        where TListType : IList<TDestinationModel>, new();
    TListType ToSource<TListType>(IEnumerable<TDestinationModel> source)
        where TListType : IList<TSourceModel>, new();


    TDestinationModel ToDestination(TSourceModel source);
    TSourceModel ToSource(TDestinationModel source);
}
```

I want to be able to call the list conversion methods in a manner such that I only have to specify the list type and not also include the contained type in the list since it is inferred from the interace definition.

Ex:
Lets say I create a implementation such that

```
FooBooModelConverter : IModelConverter<Foo,Boo>
```

... Later in my code I instantiate it as modelConverter and I would like to do the following

```
BindingList<Foo> fooList = modelConverter<BindingList>.ToDestination(booList);
```

or

```
List<Foo> fooList = modelConverter<List>.ToDestination(booList);
```

However instead I have to do the following

```
BindingList<Foo> fooList = modelConverter<BindingList<Foo>>.ToDestination(booList);
```

or

```
List<Foo> fooList = modelConverter<List<Foo>>.ToDestination(booList);
```

Respecifying Foo in the list type is redundant and ugly.

Optimally I'd love to do the following and have it automatically infer the list type by the return value, but I'll take what I can get. Anyone?

```
BindingList<Foo> fooList = modelConverter.ToDestination(booList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why construct the list inside the converter? You can return an `IEnumerable<T>` and construct the list outside:

```
public interface IModelConverter<TSourceModel, TDestinationModel>
{
    IEnumerable<TDestinationModel> ToDestination(IEnumerable<TSourceModel> source);
    IEnumerable<TDestinationModel>ToSource(IEnumerable<TDestinationModel> source);
    //...
}

var fooList = new List<Foo>(modelConverter.ToDestination(booList);
```